# It is more efficient to call object outside methods in c#?

Tags: c#

**Which is better to achieve efficiency if i need to use this object in many methods in my class?**

Doing this:

> Create object above of class so i can accecc `c` in multiple methods.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static Customers c = new Customers("text1", "text2");

    public static void Main()
    {

    }

}
```

Or doing this:

> Create object inside methods so every time i need to use `c` object i
>   must create it.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Customers c = new Customers("text1", "text2");
    }

}
```

Comment: Basically, the first is more efficient if you only _get_ that object data with a method that is called multiple times, but it ___absolutely___ depends on the situation.

Comment: Variables should be defined at the minimum necessary scope.

Comment: Are you specifically talking about Program / Main, or about classes in general?

Comment: Those two "variables" have different use cases and are not related whatsoever.

Comment: @James about classes in general.

Comment: @madreflection So, its depends.

Comment: What you should do depends on the situation. Efficiency, when it comes to variable scope, should be a secondary concern. Make sure the variable is available as long as you need it and no longer than that. Then if there's an inefficiency in doing so and expanding the scope helps, then consider doing that. Don't define a variable at a higher scope out of convenience or *expectation* of efficiency.

Comment: @madreflection, thanks for you, so I edit my post question to: if i need to use this object many times in my program.

I got it from you, so please can you write your answer then i choose it?

Comment: @ObadaDiab it is not a question of efficiency, it depends on what you need, if you define your variable inside a method, the scope of your variable will be limited by your method, otherwise if you declare your variable inside the class, the scope of this variable will be different, and of course, the memory management for the two cases is different.

Comment: Re your edit, *"if i need to use this object many times in my program"* - you have two separate concerns here and you haven't addressed the more important aspect of it, *where* you need to use it. Scope is the primary concern so address that first.

Comment: @madreflection, i think now its good xD, "use this object in many methods in my class"
sorry for bad English dude

Comment: Re your second edit, *"many methods"* - we use the term "method" but it's just a special term for function, and functions are designed to take arguments and return values. If you use it in many methods, pass it to them. A variable only belongs at the class level (making it a *field*) if control returns to the consumer between method calls.

Comment: That's a fairly pedantic stance but it's a proper starting point. Practicality may demand that you do differently, but make it the rare exception, not the rule. I hesitate to write an answer because this is the subject of entire books, plus the question is still improperly framed around efficiency. Also, variable scope is a well-discussed topic on SO. Surely, this is a duplicate of something.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113262/why-declare-variables-close-to-where-they-are-used

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally it is a best practice to restrict variables' scope(s) as much as possible ([great explaination why](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307347)). This means that if you need a variable to be accessible by multiple methods, then great, make a global variable. If not, then make it local because that's all it needs to be. Neither of these are "more efficient" than the other per-say, they are just used in different scenarios.

For example, let's say you're writing a simple calculator-like program to add/subtract 2 
 random numbers.

```
static int num1;
static int num2;

static void Main(string[] args){
    var rand = new Random();
    num1 = rand.Next(10); // Generate random number between 0 and 10
    num2 = rand.Next(10);

    Add();
    Subtract();

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Add(){
    Console.WriteLine($"{num1} + {num2} = {num1+num2}");
}

static void Subtract(){
    Console.WriteLine($"{num1} - {num2} = {num1-num2}");
}
```

In this example, `num1` and `num2` need to be processed by the `Add()` and `Subtract()` methods, so we make them global variables. The `rand` variable on the other hand is only needed in the `Main()` method, so we keep it local.

Global variables can also be accessed from within other classes (depending on their scope), whereas local variables cannot.